# "H.264 (High Profile) decoder is required to play the file"

Tags: fedora, multimedia, codec

I'm trying to play videos I recorded from my mobile phone (the stock video / photo app on a Samsung Galaxy On7).

When I click them I get the following error message from Totem on Fedora 28:

[image: H.264 (High Profile) decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed]

> H.264 (High Profile) decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed

Clicking "Find in programs" doesn't find an appropriate codec.

---

The `file` tool labels them as "ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]".

---

This is the error log when I run Totem from the CLI:

> ** Message: 12:57:35.979: Missing plugin: gstreamer|1.0|totem|H.264 (High Profile) decoder|decoder-video/x-h264, level=(string)4, profile=(string)high, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8 (H.264 (High Profile) decoder)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
sudo dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install gstreamer1-libav
```

([source](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1440331))

Comment: Thank you. On Debian 10 "Buster" that's `gstreamer1.0-libav`.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to resolve this in Fedora 38 by installing the `gstreamer1-plugin-openh264` package.