# Playing mp4 in ubuntu throws error "H.264 (High 4:4:4 Profile) decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed"

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu version 20.10

Playing any mp4 throws this error

H.264 (High 4:4:4 Profile) decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed

I am not sure this is same as the issue mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466819/h-264-high-profile-decoder-is-required-to-play-the-file)

Comment: Perhaps you need `ubuntu-restricted-formats` installed? See [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I created a movie with Kazam on ubuntu, but can't play it back :S

Answer (score -1):

you can play the videos with vlc and also with ffmpeg. But I am also on lookout for a better solution